# Toggling between full-screen with animation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make an element that is somewhere on the page (and positioned absolutely) full-screen by making it's position fixed and I want to animate the transition.

See the following code:

```js
$('.element').click(function(){
    $(this).css('left', this.getBoundingClientRect().left).css('top', this.getBoundingClientRect().top).toggleClass('fullscreen');
});
```

```css
body {padding: 50px;}
.container {position: relative; width: 100px; height: 100px; float: left;}
.element {position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: inherit; height: inherit; transition: 0s;}
.element.fullscreen {position: fixed; top: 0px !important; left: 0px !important; width: 100%; height: 100%; transition: 1s;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="element" style="background-color: red;"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="element" style="background-color: blue;"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="element" style="background-color: green;"></div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

So I start by setting the location that the element currently has (left and top), and then add the `fullscreen` class. However the order of the jQuery `css()` methods matters in this case. If `left` is set first then it animates from the correct point on the x axis but not the y axis (it jumps to the top), if `top` is set first then it's the other way around (it jumps to the left).

Why is this and how can I have it animate from both correctly?

Thanks!

Comment: Is requirement for element to have origin of animation at top-left of viewport?

Comment: No the origin of the animation is the current position of the element. I use javascript to set the current position but it only works on either top or left but not both.